# C++ function return type

Tags: c++, function, function-prototypes

With the following function prototype, how do you return a item from the list?

```
std::list<int> &GD (int);
```

Comment: The signature implies you're returning the entire list ...?

Comment: Perhaps [std::advance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) is what you are looking for? Although I am not clear of the exact question given your example.

Comment: Which item do you want to get from the list? The first? The last? All of them? If the answer is "an item with a random index" then you probably want something other than a `std::list`.

Answer (score 1):

To access an element of a list, you may call a function like:

```
int get(int index, std::list<int> const& A) {
    int i = 0;
    auto pos = A.begin();
    while(i++ < index) pos = std::next(pos);
    return *pos;
}
```

Comment: std::list doesn't have an operator[].